# Devise, Maxime, Motto – immer austauschbar?

Tags: difference

Wenn jemand oder eine Gruppe ihr Handeln nach einer bestimmten Sache ausrichtet, welche der drei Begriffe sind wann richtig, oder sind diese immer austauschbar?

> Sie handeln nach der Devise …
>   Sie handeln nach dem Motto …
>   Sie handeln nach ihrer Maxime …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nun, 'richtig' ist Sprache immer dann, wenn sie die außersprachliche Wirklichkeit 'richtig' erfasst und abbildet. Deshalb können alle drei Begriffe 'richtig' sein.

Ich sehe nur subtile Unterschiede, die bestenfalls das Maß der Missbilligung ausdrücken und situativ determiniert sind.

Wenn einer grundsätzlich immer nur an sich denkt, würde **ich** sagen: *Der handelt auch immer nur nach dem Motto: Ich, ich und nochmal ich.* "*Motto*" scheint mir das frequenteste Wort zu sein, jedenfalls in gesprochener Sprache.

*Devise* würde im genannten Beispielsatz nach meiner Einschätzung ebenso gut passen, scheint mir aber minder frequent zu sein.

Bei *Maxime* schwingt nach meiner Einschätzung etwas von *Dogma* oder *Dogmatik* mit, will sagen: es verweist deutlicher auf *Verbohrtheit* und drückt dadurch mehr Missbilligung aus als *Motto* und *Devise*. Ich würde *Maxime* eher in gehobener gesprochener oder in geschriebener Sprache erwarten.

All of this, however, IMHO. :-)

Comment: _Maxime_ ist in der deutschen Sprache durch die spezielle Verwendung durch Immanuel Kant konnotiert. In der Moralphilosophie Kants (_Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten_, _Kritik der praktischen Vernunft_) ist _Maxime_ der prinzipielle Vorsatz, nach dem eine Handlung ausgeführt wird. Dies harmoniert mit deiner Vorstellung, dass hier etwas von _Dogma_ mitschwingt, also eine eher prinzipielle Sichtweise. Wie stark diese Konnotation wahrgenommen wird, hängt natürlich auch damit zusammen, wie vertraut man mit der Moralphilosophie Kants ist.

Comment: *„Nee. Mag ich nicht. Haben Sie nicht zugehört?“
„Offensichtlich nicht“, sagt das Känguru. „Denken Sie nicht mit?“
„Nein. Nie“, sage ich. **„Ich lebe nach der Devise: Lieber fünf Mal nachgefragt als einmal nachgedacht.** Haben Sie nicht zugehört?“* Marc Uwe Kling: Die Känguru Chroniken.

Comment: Ach, jonathan, musstest du nun gleich alles über mich verraten?! Wo ich mich só bemüht habe, mich nicht zu outen. :-))

Answer (score 1):

Ich sehe zwischen

- A: Motto, Devise
- B: Maxime

den Unterschied, dass Motto und Devise eine spezifische sprachliche Formulierung meinen (z.B. einen Satz, der ein handlungsleitendes Prinzip benennt), während die Maxime das handlungsleitende Prinzip selbst meint (das auch ohne eine bestimmte sprachliche Formulierung existieren kann).

(Auf die sprachphilosophische Debatte, ob Dinge, die nicht gedanklich formuliert sind, überhaupt existieren, will ich jetzt nicht eingehen. Ebensowenig auf die Frage, ob Gedanken ohne Sprache möglich sind.)

Answer (score 1):

Es gäbe da noch

> getreu dem Wahlspruch,

was für mich am nahesten bei der 'Devise' läge. Auch

> nach der Parole / nach dem Grundsatz / nach dem Prinzip

oder ein simples

> frei nach

kommen vor. Die Wendungen werden nicht selten flapsig-ironisierend benutzt und charakterisieren Handlungsweisen, die sich nicht gut in ein einziges Wort fassen lassen:

> Nach dem Motto 'Was sollen bloß die Leute denken!' verbot sie ihrer Tochter Lippenstift und hochhackige Schuhe.

In der Regel folgen dem vorgeschalteten "nach dem Motto" und seinen Varianten Sprichwörter, sprichwortartige Sentenzen oder auch so etwas wie Totschlagargumente, frei nach dem Muster "da kann ja jeder kommen!"

Man kann nach einer Devise handeln oder verfahren und eine Veranstaltung unter ein bestimmtes Motto stellen. Mag sein, man kann auch 'nach einem Motto handeln'. Mir klingt auch ein 'etwas zur Maxime seines Handelns erklären' im Ohr.

Alle Varianten beinhalten das Moment einer - inszenierten oder geforderten - überzeitlichen Gültigkeit. Damit verbunden ist ihre Jederzeit-Wiederholbarkeit, das macht sie zu einer Art Glaubenssatz. In neuerer Zeit spricht man hier gerne von einem 'Mantra'; aus 'mehr Straßen = mehr Verkehr' als vorgeblichem oder tatsächlichem Mantra der Grünen ließe sich ein Satz ableiten wie

> Nach dem Motto 'mehr Straßen = mehr Verkehr' versucht die Partei 'die Grünen' den Ausbau von Bundesautobahnen zu verhindern.

Letztlich erscheinen mir die verschiedenen Formulierungen untereinander austauschbar und nur sekundär stilistisch markiert im Sinne der Antwort von multiplex.